# Как начать писать GUI-приложения(windows/linux/other)

Tags: linux, windows, gui

Так случилось, что пишу и основном для веба, иногда несложные консольные программки.

С чего начать писать нормальные gui-приложения? Игры в том числе :)
Как их проектировать?
Какую литературу стоит почитать, при условии начального уровня знаний?

P.s. Из языков, наверное, остановлюсь на Си или `Java`.
P.s.s. Игры упомянул, т.к. на них интереснее учиться.

---

**UPD:** полностью перефразировал вопрос.

Comment: Под джавой в целом так же, как и в никсах. На Си писать в винде как-то непринято, хотя и можно. Во всяком случае наслышан, что в VS Си несколько кривоватый.

Comment: Лучше, Си шарп

Comment: А что значит "писать под windows"? Ставите cygwin и пишите как "под линх".

Comment: @alexlz в первую очередь интересует научиться писать гуи-приложения. Консоль конечно круто, но пора из неё выбираться на свет божий.

Comment: Tcl/Tk, GTK, wxWindows, Qt... Позволяют писать гуи-приложения? Или нужно windows only?

Comment: @alexlz спасиб. Я хоть сам разобрался, чего хочу.

Comment: ИМХО, WPF - самый мощный гуй под винду

Answer (score 3):

Лично читал - 
`Programming Windows`, `5th Edition`, `by Charles Petzold` (если тебя больше инетресует UI, потом почитаешь более подробно в `MSDN - Windows Application UI Development`).

`Windows Via C/C++ - Jeffrey Richter` (если тебя больше интересует работа с процессами, потоками, мютексами, семафорами...... работа с памятью....)

Луче читать обе книги, так как они очень хорошие.

Answer (score 1):

Лучший кроссплатформенный фреймворк - Qt. Оригинальный язык С++. Имеются привязки к почти всем распространенным языкам (в том числе к Java).

Если нужен чистый С, то GTK+, но на винде работа с ним тот еще геморрой.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы посоветовал для GUI использовать JavaFX. Входит в состав Java SE, огромное количество уроков, туториалов по нему можно найти в google.

Вкратце его возможности:

- Стандартные элементы GUI (лейблы, кнопки, контейнеры, текстовые поля, т.д.)
- Применение css стилей к элементам GUI
- Canvas для отрисовки 2D (ну, это можно к стандартным приписать)
- Встроенный браузер (WebView) с возможностью проложения 'моста' между java и js
- Сенсорные события и жесты